# Save & Restore Page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm looking to save the current navigation stack on the OnSleep Event in my Xamarin Forms page and restore it on the OnResume Event. Is it possible to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not memorize all navigation stack. Your device decide to kill your app or to restart from the last page you have seen when it comes up from background. I think you can memorize if you are "Logged in" or not: if you are "Logged in" you can restart from the first page "after the login", otherwise start "from the login".

For this case you can take a look to [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#The_Application_Class) and use [Properties](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/application-class/#Properties_Dictionary)

```
public class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
{
    public App ()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        Debug.WriteLine ("OnStart");
        checkLogin();

    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
        Debug.WriteLine ("OnSleep");
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
        Debug.WriteLine ("OnResume");
        checkLogin();
    }
}

void checkLogin(){

        if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("IsLogged"))
        {
           var IsLogged = Application.Current.Properties ["IsLogged"] as bool;
           // do something with IsLogged
           if(IsLogged)
               MainPage = new MyFirstPage();
           else
               MainPage = new MyLoginPage();
        }
        else
            MainPage = new MyLoginPage();
}
```

then, when you have logged in

```
Application.Current.Properties ["IsLogged"] = true;
```

Comment: I shall clarify - that is essentially the logic I have at the minute. If they're logged in, bring them to one page and if not, bring them to another page. However, in iOS, if the user brings up the control centre, it suspends the app and when they exit the control centre, it executes the "resume" logic which i don't want.